# Issue with using AWS classic load balance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Let me introduce about my website and configuration.

I have an event booking website built in PHP with heavy user traffic. Sometimes traffic becomes double when event booking start. I've configured the EC2 instance (t2-medium), RDS (t2-medium) and S3 for my website. I'm using an AWS service called **Classic Load Balancer** (ELB)to distribute the traffic. I have attached two instances to the load balancer and if there is more traffic then it will add more EC2 instances.

The problem is that sometimes when a user sends any POST request to the server then it is sending to both EC2 instances at the same time instead of only one instance and therefore user get twice booking.

So I want to know, The way I'm using is good or not? if not then how can I handle this type of issues?

You help would be more appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "So problem is that sometimes when a user sends any post request to the server then it is sending to both ec2 instances at the same time" - where are you posting your requests? If you're posting them at the DNS endpoint for the load balancer then it should balance those requests and send them to one server, not multiple

Comment: Yes, posting to DNS endpoint for the load balancer, ticket booking flow in 3 step and in final step user submit for payment, that requests sending through both ec2 instance rather than single ec2

Comment: It sounds like something is wrong with your load balancer set up if it's sending the same traffic to multiple instances

Comment: Are you sure you are not making duplicate request to your ELB?

Check in ELB-> Monitoring tab -> Request Count. Make one request and check how many request count it logs in the ELB monitoring

Comment: No, I'm not allowing the duplicate request, I'm disabling submit button as soon as user clicks on it, so there is less chance to send duplicate requests

Comment: Could you try checking in  ELB-> Monitoring tab -> Request Count. Make one request and check how many request count it logs in the ELB monitoring ? Just to eliminate chances that request duplicating on the way before ELB.